# what is python's equivalent to ruby's collect

Tags: python

in ruby, You can do this to collect importent values from a hash:

```
        hash = {'a'=> {'consider_this' => 1, 'dont_consider_this' => 4}, 
'b' => {'consider_this' => 4, 'dont_consider_this' =>  4}}
        hash.collect{|key, value| value['consider_this']}=> [1, 4]
    => [1, 4]
```

trying to do the same in python (new to the language) but didn't managed to .

Comment: Do you even have an equivalent data structure constructed in Python?

Comment: Your code result in `[1, 1]`, not `[1, 4]`.

Comment: sure, it's a plain [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: @OhadPartuck Please include the dictionary you constructed in the question. As it is, the question looks as if you have no clue what you are doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) over the values of a dictionary:

```
nested = {
    'a': {'consider_this': 1, 'dont_consider_this': 4}, 
    'b': {'consider_this': 1, 'dont_consider_this': 4}
}
[v['consider_this'] for v in nested.values()]
```

The keys in the outer dictionary don't matter here. The output is `[1, 1]`, all values of the `consider_this` key, in arbitrary order. Also see the [`dict.values()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values). If the `consider_this` key is missing it is considered an error.

You could use filtering to only consider dictionaries with the specific key:

```
nested = {
    'a': {'consider_this': 1, 'dont_consider_this': 4}, 
    'b': {'consider_this': 2, 'dont_consider_this': 4},
    'c': {'dont_consider_this': 4},
}
[v['consider_this'] for v in nested.values() if 'consider_this' in v]
# outputs [1, 2] or [2, 1]
```

or provide a default value:

```
nested = {
    'a': {'consider_this': 1, 'dont_consider_this': 4}, 
    'b': {'consider_this': 2, 'dont_consider_this': 4},
    'c': {'dont_consider_this': 4},
}
[v.get('consider_this', 0) for v in nested.values()]
# [1, 2, 0], or alternative orders
```

The latter uses the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Consider using `{...}` (a set comprehension) rather than a list to reflect that ordering doesn't matter here; the result will only hold *unique* values, so `{1}` if all `consider_this` keys only ever have the value `1`.

Answer (score 1):

> > python (new to the language)
> >     In ruby, you can do this to collect values from a hash
>
> ```
> hash.collect{|key, value| value['consider_this']}
> ```
>
> > what is python's equivalent to ruby's collect

The equivalent in python would be:

```
d = {
    'a': {'consider_this': 1, 'dont_consider_this': 'a'}, 
    'b': {'consider_this': 4, 'dont_consider_this': 'b'},
    'c': {'hello': 2}
}

results = []

for key, val in d.items():
    x = val.get('consider_this', False)
    results.append(x)

print results

--output:--
[1, False, 4]
```

When you get a little more experience, you can learn how to create lists from loops more efficiently using what are called `list comprehensions`:

```
results = [
    val.get('consider_this', False) 
    for key, val in d.items()
]

print results

--output:--
[1, False, 4]
```

Note that in python you could use `d.values()` instead of `d.items()` because you don't use the keys:

```
results = [
    val.get('consider_this', False) 
    for val in d.values()
]

print results

--output:--
[1, False, 4]
```

In ruby 1.9+, Hashes are ordered, but in python dictionaries are not ordered, so if the order of the results is important to you, you can use python's OrderedDict:

```
import collections as coll

d = coll.OrderedDict(
    [
        ('a', coll.OrderedDict([('consider_this', 1), ('dont_consider_this', 'a')])), 
        ('b', coll.OrderedDict([('consider_this', 4), ('dont_consider_this', 'b')])),
        ('c', coll.OrderedDict([('hello', 2)]))
    ]
)

results = [
    val.get('consider_this', False) 
    for key, val in d.items()
]

print results

--output:--
[1, 4, False]
```